# Convert CDF Player Pro back into CDF Player

Tags: cdfplayer, licensing, enterprise-cdf

I have CDF Player Pro in my computer but for testing Enterprise Mathematica signed CDF files I would like to convert my CDF Player Pro back to CDF Player.  I assume that mathpass and playerpass files are key here but I have not been able to revert to the original/downloaded/standard CDF Player.

Comment: For testing purposes, File>CDF Preview may be adequate.  Otherwise, probably evaluate $PasswordFile in Player Pro, and check out that location.

Comment: @KAI: $PasswordFile returns mathpass file location.  Inside mathpass there are three sequences of characters: WolframCDFPlayer BB9... 097... 657...  Do you know what to do next?

Comment: Apparently deleting the file from the right location (strictly that provided by $PasswordFile even though the file may be in other location also) is enough.